# Button (image) not changing after being tapped

Tags: java, android, button

I have a very basic app with a button which deals with playing of sound whenever tapped. It plays until the button is pressed/tapped and once you un-tap it or untouch it the sound stops. You tap(hold) the sound keeps playing, once the button is untouched the sound stops. Now I have a button image which should change whenever its touched(music plays) and come back to default state when untouched (music stops). This thing was working fine when I was using onClickListener but once I changed it to onTouchListener , the button image never changed on tapping. Here is the MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.firozkaoo2222.myapplication;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.example.firozkaoo2222.myapplication.R.raw.police;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private MediaPlayer policeSound;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button policeSounds = findViewById(R.id.police);

    policeSounds.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (policeSound == null) {
                policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.police);
            }

            int eventPadTouch = event.getAction();

            switch (eventPadTouch) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // start playing sound , in your case:
                    policeSound.start();
                    return true;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // stop playing sound , in your case:
                    policeSound.pause();
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });}}
```

Code for activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/police"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for cutom_button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touch listener consumes the click listener and it will never reached to selector.Since you are using `pressed state` so you can imitate state pressed using `policeSounds.setPressed(boolean)` so change it

```
switch (eventPadTouch) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // start playing sound , in your case:
        policeSound.start();
        policeSounds.setPressed(true)
        return true;


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // stop playing sound , in your case:
        policeSound.pause();
        policeSounds.setPressed(false)
        return true;

}
```

Note : For convince, you can declare `policeSounds` outside `oncreate` instead of making it `final` as local variable